# C a subtract method with char[]

Tags: c++, c, math, pointers, char

I tried to implement the subtract method but got there are some bugs.

55-44 is correct
555-44 is not correct, it will return 011
100-44 will cause segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

char* subtract(char *n1,char *n2){
    int n1Len = strlen(n1);
    int n2Len = strlen(n2);


    int diff;  
    int max=n1Len;
    char* res = (char*)malloc (max+2);
    memset(res, '0', max +1); 

    res[max] = '\0';
    int i=n1Len - 1, j = n2Len - 1, k = max;
    for (; i >= 0 && j >=0; --i, --j, --k) {
        if(i >= 0 && j>=0)
        {
            diff = (n1[i] - '0') - (n2[j] - '0');
            if(diff<0)
            {
                int temp=n1[i-1]-'0';
                temp=temp-1;
                n1[i-1]=temp+'0';
                diff+=10;
            }
            res[i]=diff+'0';
        }
        else 
            res[i]=n1[i];

    }
    return res;
}


int main(void) {

    printf("%s\n",  subtract("100","44"));
}
```

Comment: Attach a debugger, step through the program, and find where your algorithm deviates from the correct behavior.  Also, mind the memory, please:  the array you allocate and return from `subtract` is never freed.

Comment: Inclusion of the headers `<iostream>` and `<sstream>` (whose content isn't used at all) it the only relationship of this C code to C++... Well, predecrement is also used while in C it would use postdecrement.

Comment: Personally, I would start with fixing the `max` to actually be the max of the two strings. Although unrelated to your problem note that `(n1[i] - '0') - (n2[j] - '0')` is identical to `n1[i] - n2[j]`. One definite problem is that the code handles the first string being longer but not the second string being longer.

Comment: thanks, finally switched to java...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote it in GMP just for kicks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>

char* subtract(char *n1,char *n2){
  mpz_t n1z, n2z;
  char * res = malloc(strlen(n1) > strlen(n2) ? strlen(n1) + 1 : strlen(n2) + 1);
  mpz_init_set_str(n1z, n1, 10);
  mpz_init_set_str(n2z, n2, 10);
  mpz_sub(n2z, n1z, n2z);
  gmp_sprintf(res, "%Zd", n2z);
  mpz_clear(n1z);
  mpz_clear(n2z);
  return res; 
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%s\n",  subtract("55","44"));
  printf("%s\n",  subtract("555","44"));
  printf("%s\n",  subtract("100","44")); 
}
```

Comment: You need to compile (in linux) with: gcc file.c -o file -lgmp

Comment: thanks a lot.  I finally switched to Java... BigInteger

Comment: Sure. If you need speed, GMP is a lot faster than BigInteger. Like a couple of orders of magnitude for some things, and especially when the numbers get big. Java is nice and easy sometimes, though, for stuff where speed doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that 555-44 doesn't work is that you test the same condition in the 'for' statement as you do in the 'if' statement. That causes the loop to exit early if one string is longer than the other.

The reason 100-44 causes a segmentation fault is that you are trying to write back into a constant string.

Your borrow logic also doesn't account for borrowing from '0'.

Answer (score 0):

How about just

```
int i1 = atoi(n1);
int i2 = atoi(n2);
int result = i1 - i2; 
char * retval = malloc(2*strlen(n1)); // Easier than figuring out exact right size!
sprintf(retval, "%d", result);
return retval;
```

Wouldn't that be a lot nicer?

Comment: thanks. but I can't do that.  I am dealing with very large numbers and gmp doesn't work.  So, this is my only option

Comment: gmp is awesome. why doesn't it work?

Comment: GMP can't handle your big numbers?  That is surprising!  Are you sure you can handle GMP?

Comment: yeah, i know gmp works, but don't know how to use gmp properly.  running my c++ on my school's server and they don't have gmp installed, sorry